# Firefox Addon SDK feature for User Identity

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, user-identification

I'm using Firefox Addon SDK, and have already developed an Chrome Extension.

I was searching similar to function available in [Chrome Apps Identity Feature](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo) in Firefox but was unable to do so.

I have been through [Firefox UUID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/system#id) for browser, but as this can differ between devices, I need some id which will uniquely define a user rather than Browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is if the user has synced their Firefox to an account? Check out this page in firefox - about:preferences?entrypoint=menupanel#sync

Firefox has profiles but they are not user tied. This is an example of different profiles in Firefox - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/profilist/